# MongoDB: unable to load driver on PHP

Tags: mongodb, php

I'm trying to make [mongo-php-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) work with **PHP 5.5.7** on **OS X 10.9.1** but I came to a dead end, I've tried everything I could possibly find and nothing works...

Everything compiles just fine, but PHP doesn't load the extension and gives a really odd error:

```
Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mongo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mongo.so, 9): Symbol not found: _core_globals
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mongo.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I've checked about thread safety and architecture issues but everything is just fine, both extension and PHP are thread safe and 64bits.

I also checked if there was any issues with the binaries, like `phpize` and `php-config`, but everything seems to be just fine...

I really don't know what to do, anyone has any clue?

---

As pointed out by [voretaq7](https://serverfault.com/questions/563867/mongodb-unable-to-load-driver-on-php/563922#comment655318_563867) and [MadHatter](https://serverfault.com/questions/563867/mongodb-unable-to-load-driver-on-php/563922#comment655813_563867) this is what I did:

1. Downloaded PHP 5.5.7 and compiled with
   `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs`;
2. Downloaded the [master](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) branch of the mongo driver and compiled with default configuration as [instructed](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/README.md#installation);
3. Included the extension in php.ini:
   `extension = mongo.so`;
4. Ran `php -v` and got the odd error I said before;
5. Checked if PHP and the driver were being compiled in 64 bits, they were;
6. Checked if `phpize` and `php-config` were the ones installed earlier in step 1, they were;
7. Yelled *fuck this shit* and asked for help.
8. Realized I could try with the 1.4.5 driver version. *BAM!* done, everything works now.

Comment: The OS X implementation of dlopen() can't parse the SO correctly, for reasons that might also have to do with the SO file.  Why are you doing this on OS X?

Comment: "I've tried everything I could possibly find" is less than helpful. ***What***, *SPECIFICALLY* have you tried? How did you build the driver? etc...

Comment: @FalconMomot it seems to be an issue with the latest version of the driver, I tried the 1.4.5 and everything went just fine.

Comment: @voretaq7 sorry about the confusing question, but I said what I tried in the last paragraphs.

Comment: Don't **tell** us what you did.  **Show** us what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is only happening on the [lastest version](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/tree/6e4108d98912483f7e37523944df0518c887806e).

I just tried with the [1.4.5](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/tree/861d4b8c70accf09e4481d004cd52572287e36a2) and everything went just fine!